# node-red split, reorder and join an output string

Tags: node-red

I am trying to reorder an output string in node-red like the following example:

Output:

```
msg.payload: rgb(152,11,100)
```

I want to have it like this:

```
mg.payload: rgb(11,100,152)
```

I tried with `split` node using `,` string, then I got three outputs, but I could not join them again with the order I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably just with a regex in a function node.

```
var re = /rgb\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)/;
var match = re.exec(msg.payload);
msg.payload= "rbg(" + match[2] + "," + match[3] + "," + match[1] + ")";
return msg
```

Answer (score 0):

I got another answer which also work (thanks to [z1rconium](https://www.reddit.com/user/z1rconium))

use a function node:

```
input = msg.payload
str = input.substr(4,input.indexOf(")")-4)
out = str.split(",");
// creates an array you can use;
// out[0] = 152
// out[1] = 11
// out[2] = 100
return {payload:"rgb("+out[1]+","+out[2]+","+out[0]+")"}
//msg.payload : string[14]
//"rgb(11,100,152)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative code to use inside a function node. It uses ES6 capabilities:

```
let pay = msg.payload.slice(4, -1).split(",");
let [r,g,b] = [...pay];
msg.payload = `rgb(${g},${b},${r})`;
return msg;
```